# How to resolve Error converting .3ds file to .stl

Tags: python, 3ds, stl-format, freecad

I am working on a project to convert various file formats to .stl. I have succeeded converting .step, .igs, .dae and .obj file to .stl. Whenever I try to convert .3ds file to .stl, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "3DFileFormatConversion.py", line 141, in 
>       import3DS.open(INPUT)
>       File "/usr/share/freecad/Mod/Arch/import3DS.py", line 59, in open
>       read(filename)
>       File "/usr/share/freecad/Mod/Arch/import3DS.py", line 92, in read
>       for j,d_nobj in enumerate(dom.mdata.objects):
>
> AttributeError: 'UnknownChunk' object has no attribute 'mdata'

The code I am using for this conversion is as follows:

```
import import3DS
import3DS.open(INPUT)
App.setActiveDocument(INPUTFILE)
App.ActiveDocument=App.getDocument(INPUTFILE)
__objs__=[]
for mesh in FreeCAD.getDocument(INPUTFILE).Objects:
    __objs__.append(mesh)
Mesh.export(__objs__,OUTPUT)
del __objs__
```

I get an error in the import3Ds.open(INPUT) command, where INPUT is the input file name. The weird part is that this code executes completely fine on a Windows platform. However, when I tried running it on Ubuntu 18.04, it gives me the above mentioned error. Can someone point whats going on here?

Code reference for import3DS library can be found [here](https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD/blob/master/src/Mod/Arch/import3DS.py)

Answer (score 1):

Can't duplicate your problem.  It works for me. 
There might be a problem with your input file.
Please post to the FreeCAD forum along with your FreeCAD version information.

Comment: The problem was with Python version. It turns out that import3DS imports another file (Dice3DS) which only runs for Python 2. I installed FreeCAD for Python2 and all the dependencies on my Linux machine and it works fine. I believe your version of FreeCAD will be running Python 2. Thanks for the response though.